# Why am I getting a positive strong regression coefficient with a very weak correlation?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, p-value, pearson-r

I am trying to understand what factors contribute most to my overall spending. I used data on my monthly spending from 2018 to Oct 2020. Essentially my dependent variable is total spend and I have other independent variables as eating out, retail shopping, supermarkets, and others. I ran a multiple regression and everything looks fine except for the relationship between my spend on supermarkets and total spending.

When I run a normal correlation, I find a very weak correlation between supermarket spend and a total spend of 0.02, however, in the regression model I get a coefficient of 1.82  with a P-value lower 0. My interpretation would be for every $1 spent on supermarkets my total spending should increase by 1.82, even though when I plot the relationship it doesn't look like so (weak correlation).

I check for multicollinearity where I removed all the variables that have a strong correlation with supermarkets spend but still didn't work.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are running a regression with more than 10 independent regressors and with only 22 observations- that is some serious overfitting, you can’t take results from such model seriously. At very least you would want to have about 25-30 observations per independent regressor and there might be other issues with your regression as well.

Comment: Hussein Ahmen, glad you're experimenting with regression to understand your spending. Mind taking a look at plots of Retail Shopping versus the other variables (one at a time) and reporting back with any strong relationships?

Comment: @BenOgorek, thank you for your help. In fact, I calculated the VIF for each variable against the other, and there were all between 1 to 1.3 - I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Remember that x's effect might look insignificant in the model y ~ x but look very significant in the model y ~ x + z. When you add other regressors, all bets are off. What happens if you leave just supermarket spend out of the model and plot supermarket spend against the model errors?

Comment: @BenOgorek, in fact, I incorrectly calculated the VIF - You were correct on the first comment. There seem to be some variables with VIF >5. I posted a screenshot above.   (Note: you may find additional variables, that didn't exist before, also Food Supply is the same thing as supermarkets - apologize for the confusions)

Comment: Eating out and retail shopping are 0.50 correlated! thank you so much @BenOgorek and 1muflon1  learned something new today :- )